# HP calculator with redefinable keyboard

Tags: calculator

A year or so ago, I read about an HP calculator that was completely reprogrammable, down to *redefining the keys*. And I think it was of relatively recent vintage.

I can't figure out which one it was, because when I search for programmable HP calculator, I get the usual suspects, which are programmable in the way calculators are traditionally programmable.

What was that calculator? Was I just dreaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the description of [HP 49g+](http://reviews.pricegrabber.com/calculators/m/3184243/) says that "...and with every key being user definable, you can swap out lesser used functions...", perhaps that's the one?

Comment: Close enough. Further research leads me to believe that what I read about was the HP 50g--the latest in the 49 series.

Comment: Considering how disappointed I was with the 49g, I don't think I'll ever buy another of the HP programmable calculators. These days I tend to pop up Matlab and the symbolic toolbox they bought from MuPAD instead, at least on a pc.

Comment: And I still don't understand why they aren't provided backlighting on these in 2009.

Comment: Why were you disappointed? Have they lost the classic "feel?"

Comment: Yeah, I had an older HP before, which we even "upgraded" with more memory by opening the case and soldering in more memory, like 15 years ago. It worked wonders, and felt sturdy and solid. The 49g+ just felt... cheap. Add to that that I went through all the units in the store in order to find one that all the buttons worked on without me having to press it through the casing, and it felt like HP just didn't give a crap any more. Knowing what I know now about the calculator part of HP I guess they didn't at that time.